# React Native - View won't take all available space with header and footer

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a page with a header and a footer, and between them have a View taking all the remaining space, but the View only takes half of the available space, like in the picture below :

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAeys.png)

Here is the pertinent code :

```jsx
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", height: 120 }}>

    <View style={{ height: 70, borderWidth: 2 }}>
      <Text> HEADER </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "space-between",
      height: 50,
      alignItems: "center",
      borderWidth: 2,
    }}>
      // Buttons and stuff ..
    </View>

  </View>

  <View style={{ padding: 15, borderWidth: 2, flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}><Text>Desired Content</Text></View>
  </View>

  <View style={{
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
  }}>
    // Here is my footer ..
  </View>

</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you set `flex: 1` to the view wrapping your header.

Try simply removing it :

```jsx
<View style={{flexDirection: 'column', height: 120}}>
```